# How to set a time limit or relaxation parameter for objective function using GLPK in Python?

Tags: python, pulp, glpk

I am using pulp interface to run GLPK MIP solver. 
To solve an objective function I put this:
GLPK().solve(problem)

What parameter and how should I use to set time limit or relaxation parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the list `options` when calling the solver to specify all the options you would like to use.

For example, with

```
prob.solve(pulp.GLPK_CMD(msg=1, options=["--tmlim", "10","--interior"]))
```

I set the time limit to 10 seconds and I ask explicitly for the interior point method when solving the LP.

For a complete list of parameters you can check `glpsol --help`.

Comment: It is not working for me:.... Error while executing glpsol.exe. However Idea is good. Found out that gap is working when used this way e.g. solve(GLPK(options=['--mipgap', '0.02']))

Comment: What error do you get? I've tested it and it works for me.

Comment: I solved it using workaround method. Took your framework and used mipgap instead tmlim. Anyway I got what I desired.